# Linq any - How to select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have some simple classes that looks like this:

```
Class Favorites
Guid UserId
Guid ObjectId

Class Objects
Guid Id
String Name
```

With Entity Framework I want to select all the Objects which has been marked as a favorite by a user.

So I tried something like this

```
context.Objects.Where(
   x => x.Id == 
   context.Favorite.Where(f => f.UserId == UserId)
   .Select(f => f.ObjectId).Any()
);
```

But I don't get it. I also tried with intersect, but what I understand it most be the same type. One User can have many Favorite objects

Comment: Do you have navigational properties, i.e. Favorite.Object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use join clause:

```
context.Favorite
  .Where(f => f.UserId == UserId)
  .Join(context.Objects, t => t.ObjectId, u => u.Id, (t, u) => t);
```

Comment: Ahsant, ye +1 ham az tarafe ma

Answer (score 4):

I'd do a join, my linq would look like:

```
var matches = from o in context.Objects
join f in context.Favorite on o.Id equals f.ObjectId
where f.UserId == UserId
select o;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from o in context.Objects
join f in context.Favorites on o.Id equals f.ObjectId
where f.UserId == @userId
select //whatever you wants
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FirstOrDefault() instead of Any()

Comment: I updated the question. One user have many favorites. So first or default only match the first

Answer (score 0):

your favorites class needs a property that links it back to the objects, and instead of the double where clauses you can use an Include

Classes

```
Class Favorites
    Guid UserId
    Guid ObjectId
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    Objects objs

Class Objects
    Guid Id
    String Name
```

Linq

```
context.Favorites.Include(objs).Where(x => x.UserID == UserID)
```

Then you Favorites object would have a collection of objects under it.